# Format Pandas date array with mixed formats

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, format

I'm trying to unify dates in a column as they come in different formats; current date entries:

[... '18-Aug-21' '16-Aug-21' '17-Aug-21'
'22-Aug-21' '21-Aug-21' '20-Aug-21' '19-Aug-21' '23-Aug-21' '24-Aug-21'
'25-Aug-21' '28-Aug-21' '26-Aug-21' '27-Aug-21' '31-Aug-21' '30-Aug-21'
'29-Aug-21' '06 Sep 2021' '07 Sep 2021' '23 Sep 2021' '17 Sep 2021'
'18 Sep 2021' '30 Sep 2021' '11 Sep 2021' '12 Sep 2021' '20 Sep 2021'
'15 Sep 2021' '16 Sep 2021' '08 Sep 2021' '09 Sep 2021' '24 Sep 2021'
'25 Sep 2021' '03 Sep 2021' '10 Sep 2021' '19 Sep 2021' '01 Sep 2021'
'29 Sep 2021' '26 Sep 2021' '27 Sep 2021' '13 Sep 2021' '14 Sep 2021'
'02 Sep 2021' '04 Sep 2021' '05 Sep 2021' ...

#1: trying to replace the dash here doesn't work on all dates

#2: when the year is YY as in '6-Aug-21', how can I format it?

```
for date in DF_all["SALES_DATE"]:
    date = date.replace("-"," ")

DF_all["SALES_DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(DF_all["SALES_DATE"], format='%d 
%b%Y', errors='ignore')

print(DF_all["SALES_DATE"].unique())
```

Output:

[...'18-Aug-21' '16-Aug-21' '17-Aug-21'
'22-Aug-21' '21-Aug-21' '20-Aug-21' '19-Aug-21' '23-Aug-21' '24-Aug-21'
'25-Aug-21' '28-Aug-21' '26-Aug-21' '27-Aug-21' '31-Aug-21' '30-Aug-21'
'29-Aug-21' '06 Sep 2021' '07 Sep 2021' '23 Sep 2021' '17 Sep 2021'
'18 Sep 2021' '30 Sep 2021' '11 Sep 2021' '12 Sep 2021' '20 Sep 2021'
'15 Sep 2021' '16 Sep 2021' '08 Sep 2021' '09 Sep 2021' '24 Sep 2021'
'25 Sep 2021' '03 Sep 2021' '10 Sep 2021' '19 Sep 2021' '01 Sep 2021'
'29 Sep 2021' '26 Sep 2021' '27 Sep 2021' '13 Sep 2021' '14 Sep 2021'
'02 Sep 2021' '04 Sep 2021' ...]

Is there a preferred method in python that solves this issue?

Comment: Please send your data as text rather than an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend [`dateutil`](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/) for this:

```py
import dateutil
DF_all["SALES_DATE"] = DF_all["SALES_DATE"].apply(dateutil.parser.parse)
```

Output:

```py
>>> DF_all
0    2021-08-18
1    2021-08-16
2    2021-08-17
3    2021-08-22
4    2021-08-21
5    2021-08-20
6    2021-08-19
7    2021-08-23
8    2021-08-24
9    2021-08-25
...
Name: 0, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

You might need to install `dateutil` first. Run the following in a terminal:

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

Or, in IPython or a Jupyter Notebook, run:

```
!pip install python-dateutil
```

Comment: dateutil does solve the problem but the array is not a string array anymore which would pose an issue later on such as when trying to find the unique dates print(DF_all["SALES_DATE"].unique()) which prints the date with timestamp

Comment: I don't quite understand - will you please clarify?